# Phrase request for 'Choice Robot'

Tags: phrase-requests

There is a phrase in Turkish `Tercih Robotu(Choice Robot)` I need the English word for it, let me explain what it is.

In Turkey before going to any university you should pass through a set of exams then your point is calculated, there are several point types, then by looking at those points you can estimate which univerity you can go :) And I am developing an application which does that for you in English.

What might be the right phrase or word for this?

Comment: Sorting hat....

Comment: haha :) clever :) but I wondered will this phrase be only understandable for people who knows Harry Potter? Or did this term exist before Harry Potter too?

Comment: Sort of Degree Allocator...

Comment: *Triage* is not exact, but carries the correct flavor.

Comment: Who at college age would not know sorting hat? I want percentages of you Sorting Hat App if it takes off :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a little applications all over the internet for projecting and comparing  insurance eligibility, savings growth, computer needs and the like, and they are usually called *calculators*. *College choice calculator* might work.

Or if you want something a little more whimsical, you might consider "Matriculator".

Comment: +1 for Matriculator. It can't be bargained with. It can't be reasoned with. It doesn't feel pity, or remorse, or fear. And it absolutely will not stop, ever, until you are in the right university.

Comment: +1 Yes, this is indeed the best answer - "College choice calculator".  The word "college" has a somewhat different meaning in Turkey, and that might be the only sticking point.  "University choice calculator"?

Comment: @Sabuncu Absolutely. Write for your audience, not mine.

Comment: Thanks @StoneyB.  College ("Kolej" in Turkish) was initially used for certain private charter schools in Turkey and therefore has come to be associated with high school level education.

Answer (score 0):

The best phrase I know for this is *decision tree*, but I think that's technical jargon, which will not necessarily be understood by the general public.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, UCAS has a tariff (number of points for pre-university qualifications) which can be used in this way. There's a ***[Calculator](http://alan.co.uk/ucas)*** available which shows which universities it's worth applying to.

Comment: My 30-year-old A-level results aren't worth anything, it seems.